# Do I need TeamID Prefix for webcredentials in the apple-app-site-association file?

Tags: ios, associated-domains, apple-app-site-association

If my app's bundleid is com.foo.bar, do I need to prefix it with my TeamID in the apple-app-site-association file webcredentials or no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.
As per Apple's Associated Domains [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) you need your App ID prefix (which is also referred to as 'Team ID'):

```
<Application Identifier Prefix>.<Bundle Identifier>
```

[image: Apple Developer page]